# Understanding get/post ajax requests to make a slideshow

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slideshow

If I have a request like the one below:

```
$next.click(function() {
      $.get("gallery_.php", function(data) {

})
```

What would the PHP code look like for the data variable?

I'm trying to learn this through w3 schools and the examples there have asp files as the URL which is why I'm confused.
So if I had an array of pictures, I want to  get the previous or next index when next is clicked.

Comment: Not really sure what you're actually trying to ask here - if the question is "is data a variable?" then yes.

Comment: yes it is.jquery inject data variable

Comment: So what does the php look like for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the complete array with the parameters you only need to handle that info with your php.

If not, try to add the current index of your slide and handle that index on php side to return the next slide.

Something like this:

```
 $next.click(function() {
 $.get("gallery_.php?index=" + currentIndex, function(data) {

     // more code
 });
```

Comment: Okay I think that's what I need. So if I have my php array being $pic_array, how would use that index. $pic_array[index] won't work because that isn't a php variable correct?

Comment: You need to catch that your index var on the server side with $_GET["index"] in order to use it. Try to learn a little bit more about the HTTP protocol and how it works

Comment: One last question, you've been a great help. Is there a way a could make a statement like this if ($_GET["index"]) {
    $index = $_GET["index"];
}
else {
    $index = 0;
}

Comment: Yyou should use isset function on PHP to check if the var has a value. Don't forget mark the answer as correct

Comment: Yeah I found that on google and I just remembered to checkmark it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking. If you are tying to make a next <-> previous to slid show images using PHP try arrays.

You can try it this way.

```
$images = array(
'1' => 'images/sample1.jpg',
'2' => 'images/sample2.jpg',
'3' => 'images/sample3.jpg',
'4' => 'images/sample4.jpg',
'5' => 'images/sample5.jpg'
);
$key = $_GET['key'];
$next = $key + 1;
$prev = $key - 1;
```